# Update SQL Server table with button from Gridview with C# on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

UPDATE:  updated code according to katstevens explanation.

I have a table that is updated with a non-fixed number of people that is used to track attendance.  I need to update the table when the user clicks a button with weather or not they arrived, in other words, when the user arrives they find their name and click a button that should fire the code behind to perform an update on their information ONLY.

I thought that a Gridview would be ideal for this because it would adapt to the various number of attendees.  I am discovering that the findcontrol method does not function as it should in that my update statement cannot find the label in the itemtemplate field.  Is there another way to do this so that the code behind can find the contol AND the view will be able to display all of the attendees regardless of how many?

This particular code is returning this error: CS0103: The name 'FIRST_NAME' does not exist in the current context

Here is the latest attempt (of many), just in case its fixable.

Code behind: commented out

Here is the sqldatasourcecontrol:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myconnection %>"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE mytable SET CHECK_IN = 1 where mytable.[ID] = @lbl_ID"
    SelectCommand="select command stuff...

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="more select stuff..." PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LBL_ID" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here is the button:

```
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btntkchkin" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Check In" OnClick="btntkchkin_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you post the full sub/function from your code behind? it appears the FIRST_NAME variable is not in scope when you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly let me clarify a few points of your question:

Many **databound Controls** will all handle any number of rows of data (your 'number of attendees') - they will just keep repeating until all data is bound. They vary somewhat in terms of layout and presentation (grid, list, with/without paging, etc.) but they underlying principle is that they will display as many or few rows as you bind to them. These include **GridView** (table display only), **ListView** (custom layout you design, either vertical or horizontal) and **Repeater** mainly.

Your **query** that is run in the code behind has a few problems. First you parse our the four variables you want to use, then you create the command. You don't supply any parameters in the query, but you inject 2 strings (FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME). Then you bind the four variables to the parameters collection, which doesn't contain any parameters.

### Refactored Code, With Explanation

```
string CommandText = "UPDATE [mytable] SET CHECK_IN = 1 where mytable.[FIRST_NAME] = @FirstName and[mytable].[LAST_NAME] = @LastName";
```

The two placeholders starting with `@` (`@FirstName`, `@LastName`) are **parameters** and are placeholders for values you add to the `Parameters` collection.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, conn))
{
```

It is good practice to wrap both the connection and the command in using blocks so that they are disposed of correctly when you are finished. Putting them one above the other just means the same set of `{ }` applies to both.

```
    string FIRST_NAME = ((Label)(GridView1.FindControl("lbl_FIRST_NAME")));
    string LAST_NAME = ((Label)(GridView1.FindControl("lbl_LAST_NAME")));
    string SESSION_ID = ((Label)(GridView1.FindControl("lbl_SESSION_ID")));
    string ID = ((Label)(GridView1.FindControl("lbl_ID"))).Text;
```

You don't actually need these variables, and they won't be found in the `GridView` directly anyway (see below), but I've left them in anyway in case you needed them.

We don't need to bind the `Connection` to the `Command` because we did that in the `using()` block before.

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FIRST_NAME);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LAST_NAME);
```

`cmd.Parameters.Add` is deprecated in newer versions of .NET, replaced by `.AddWithValue`, which allows you specify the parameter name and the value at the same time.

We don't need to bind the `@SSN_ID` and `@ID` because they aren't specified in the query. If you want to add them in, you need to modify the `UPDATE` statement of the command to include these values. If you want to use them, bind them in the same way as above.

```
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Finally we open the connection then execute the query. No need to close anything; they will dispose automagically.

```
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Then we rebind the data source to retrieve the updated values.

### Finding a control in a GridView

Unfortunately when a `GridView` renders it adds extra containers to hold the data in a table. If you think about it, running `.FindControl()` on the `GridView` wouldn't work, because the control you seek will exist for each row of the `GridView`.

To solve your problem, and not make things any harder than they need to be, I would do the following:

Add an `UpdateCommand` to your data source that updates the relevant row with the relevant data (current time, checked in flag, whatever):

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [mytable] SET CHECK_IN = 1 where mytable.[FIRST_NAME] = @First_Name AND [mytable].[LAST_NAME] = @Last_Name"
```

Add the two parameters to the `UpdateParameters` section so that the values are bound when the query is run.

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="First_name" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Last_name" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Then set the `CommandName` of the button to `Update` so that it fires the update event on the row.

```
<asp:Button ID="btntkchkin" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Update" Text="Check In" OnClick="btntkchkin_Click"/>
```

Lastly, on your `GridView`, set `DataKeyNames="FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME"` so that the `DataSource` knows to bind these values into the query.

Essentially what will happen is whenever the `btntkchkin` button is clicked, it will postback to the server and run the `UpdateCommand` by filling in any parameters from the row the button was in. This gets executed on the server, and the page will reload in the browser. I believe it will also call `DataBind` on the data source for you - if not, you can always add an event handler to do that explicitly.

### Bonus Advice

Personally I would use a Unique ID field to update the Checked In time, rather than matching on First and Last names - what happens if you have two people with the same name?

You can add the additional fields (SSN_ID, ID) to the UPDATE command by adding them in with a parameter placeholder (@SSN_ID, @ID), then adding the `asp:Parameter` to the `UpdateParameters` section. If your labels are set to `Bind()` then the `DataSource` will bind them to all query fields automatically when you run the command.

Leave a comment if any of this doesn't work or doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Finally got this figured out but your you definitely gave me HUGE push in the right direction.  Cant thank you enough.